# How to create regular expression for java like sql

Tags: java, regex

I want to search using pattern.

```
String s ="abstract-package-value";
```

Suppose I want to search for word which has 'value' in 3rd position.

I want a pattern like `*-*-value`

```
various-paint-kindness
```

Here, suppose `*-paint-*`.

In sql, I can make like `%-paint-%`

Comment: [String.contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-)?

Comment: Maybe `^.*-.*-value$` ? test what you need on i.e. https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks Turo.. it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular example, you may simply split the input string on `-` and then check the third element:

```
String s = "abstract-package-value";
String[] parts = s.split("-");
if ("value".equals(parts[2])) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

If you want a pattern matching solution, then `String#matches` with regex is another option:

```
String s = "abstract-package-value";
if (s.matches(".*-value")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

You could also use `String#endsWith` here as well, which would be similar to the `matches` option given above.

Comment: Thanks Tim.. I can use .* in pattern instead of % in sql .. right?

Comment: More or less, yes `.*` in regex is analogous to `%` in SQL like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code  and use the variations you would like :

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher; 
import java.util.regex.Pattern; 

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        
        String ss ="abstract-package-value";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*-value"); 
        Matcher mm = pattern.matcher(ss); 
        while (mm.find()) 
            System.out.println("Pattern found from position " + mm.start() +   " to " + (mm.end()-1)); 
    } 
}
```

Output :

```
Pattern found from position 0 to 21
```